# Component event handler receiving props of different component in list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following component called PrivateReview, that has event handlers for updating it's content.

```js
export default function PrivateReview(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    
    const removeReviewAndReload = async () => {
      await fetch(`/rest/review/${props.movieId}`, deleteHeaders);
      props.onChange();
    };

    const updateRating = async (event, newRating) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      
      const data = {
        rating: newRating,
      };
      await fetch(`/rest/rating/${props.movieId}`, {...updateHeaders, body: JSON.stringify(data)});
      props.onChange();
    };

    const updateReview = async (event, newComment) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const data = {
        comment: newComment,
      };

      await fetch(`/rest/review/${props.movieId}`, {...updateHeaders, body: JSON.stringify(data)});
      props.onChange();
    };

    return (
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Card style={{width: 1150, margin: 10}}>
              <CardHeader
                title={<Link href={`/Movie/${props.movieId}`} className={classes.title} style={{ fontSize: '30px' }}>{props.title}</Link>}
                action={
                  <Box component="fieldset" mb={-1} borderColor="transparent" marginTop={5}>
                    <Rating name="read-only" precision={0.5} value={props.rating} onChange={updateRating} />
                  </Box>
                }
              />
            <CardContent>
              {props.text}
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions className={classes.right}>
              <EditReviewButton movieId={props.movieId} oldReview={props.text} onSubmit={updateReview}/>
              <IconButton color="primary" component="span" className={classes.control} onClick={removeReviewAndReload}>
                <DeleteIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Button disabled color="secondary">
                {props.postDate}
            </Button>
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
    );
  }
```

I map the review data that I receive from a parent component and try to generate a list of rendered components.

```js
  const Reviews = reviews.map(({ movieName, movieId, comment, rating, post_date, user }) => {
    return <PrivateReview 
      key={movieId}
      title={movieName}
      text={comment}
      rating={rating}
      postDate={post_date}
      user={user.userId}
      movieId={movieId}
      onChange={props.reloadDashboardData}
    />;
  });
```

My problem is that when updateRating gets called, `props.movieId` is set to the movieId of the first item in the list inside updateRating, and hence the first item in the list gets modified instead of the item that I want.

Outside of this particular function however, when I `console.log(props.movieId)` in the function body, `props.movieId` is set correctly. This is the case for the other update methods as well, such as `removeReviewAndReload` and `updateReview`.

I suspect that this has something to do with either closing over the wrong value, or the bare asynchronous fetch calls. Could anyone point out the incorrectness or what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

As suggested in the comments below, I've changed the key property used in the list, and created a somewhat minimal running version here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-framework-382hq

There are 3 event handlers in PrivateReview.js, `removeReview`, `updateReview`, and `updateRating`. `removeReview` and `updateReview` correctly log the corresponding movieId of the review that they are associated with, but `updateRating` logs the movieId of the review at the top of the rendered list.

I've removed the async/await things in the linked sandbox, but the bug is still there, so I think can rule out problems with fetch and async stuff. I've updated the tags accordingly.

Thanks very much for your help so far!

**EDIT 2:**

Since I've super simplified the event handlers in the sandbox to the point where they are only console logging, I think it might have something to do with material-ui, or my component layout structure (the DOM thing but for components). I've added the material-ui tag to this question in case it has something to do with that.

Cheers

Comment: is the movieId here unique ?

Comment: Did you duplicated values of movieId when console.log? If so, that might be the problem and you may want to replace `key={movieId}` so a unique id, like reviewId for example

Comment: Could you create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue and share here to be live debugged? Often you'll find your issue when attempting to distill your code down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. `movieId` was unique in this case, but I've changed it to use the list index just in case in the sandbox linked above. @DrewReese

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much for your help and comments guys!

After minifying my example into the sandbox, and removing all the extraneous stuff, I found out the problem.

In my example, the name was set as such:

```js
<Rating name="read-only" precision={0.5} value={props.rating} onChange={updateRating} />
```

However as stated here: https://material-ui.com/pt/api/rating/

> The name attribute of the radio input elements. If readOnly is false,
> the prop is required, this input name`should be unique within the
> parent form.

Changing that to this:

```js
                    
<Rating name={`${props.movieId}`} precision={0.5} value={props.rating} onChange={updateRating} />
```

And everything works! Therefore I just needed to set the rating "name" attribute to a uniqueId associated with the review much in the same way as we need to set the key for components that are part of a list.

Cheers for your feedback!